# Find child resources' total attachment storage usage - Paperclip Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum, paperclip, rails-activerecord, nested-resources

I am building a rails app which has the models `Users`, `Album` (as in photo album) and `Photo`, nested in that order. I want to be able to find the total storage space used by a user's albums.

From the `Album` level, I can find the total storage space used by the photos in that album. i.e:

```rb
album = Album.first

album.photos.sum(:image_file_size)
```

But, I want to be able to do this from the `User` level for all albums' photos.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that each `User` has many `Albums` and each `Album` has many `Photos`. You may get the total storage used for the first `User` using the below statement.

```
User.find(1).albums.map(&:photos).flatten.pluck(:image_file_size).sum
```